# How can I center all the text vertically in this table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}% Agrupamento de colunas em tabelas
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{float} 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|l|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Comportamento elástico}& \multicolumn{ 3}{l|}{Coeficiente de poisson, $\nu$} & 0,42 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 3}{l|}{Módulo de elasticidade, E} & 1730 MPa \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Comportamento plástico} & \multicolumn{ 3}{l|}{Ângulo de fricção interna, $\psi$} & \ang{38,5}\\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 3}{l|}{Ângulo de fluxo interno, $\beta$} & \ang{38,5} \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 3}{l|}{Rácio de fluxo interno, K} & 1 \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{ 3}{l|}{Tensão de rotura à tração, $\sigma_{ut}$} & 32,6 MPa \\ \cline{ 2- 5}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} & \multicolumn{ 3}{l|}{Tensão de rotura à compressão, $\sigma_{uc}$} & 56,3 MPa \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

NEW IMAGE :

[image]

Comment: the   code :  ''m{\tempwidth}'',  doesn't work in my code table.

Comment: why have you declared a 5 column table and then used \multicolumn in every entry so that it appear as three columns? You couldremove all the  `\multicolumn`

Comment: i used the calc2latex macro, and this macro created \multicolumn in every entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load `multirow`. As the table overflowed into the margin, I added the `geometry` package, to have more sensible margins, and systematically used the `siunitx` package to have a thin unbreakable space between number and unit. Here is a simple code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}% Agrupamento de colunas em tabelas
\usepackage{array, multirow, caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{copy-decimal-marker}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Comportamento elástico}&{Coeficiente de Poisson, $\nu$} & 0,42 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & Módulo de elasticidade, E & \SI{1730}{\MPa} \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Comportamento plástico} & & \ang{38,5}\\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & Ângulo de fluxo interno, $\beta$ & \ang{38,5} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & Rácio de fluxo interno, K & 1 \\ \cline{ 2-3}
 & Tensão de rotura à tração, $\sigma_{ut}$ & \SI{32,6}{\MPa} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & Tensão de rotura à compressão, $\sigma_{uc}$ & \SI{56,3}{\MPa} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bernard, i used the calc2latex macro. thank you for your code, but i have another problem , i want to center the values of the third column, can you fix it? thanks!

Comment: @Paulo B: you just have to use the `c`column specifier. In my updated answer, I also use the `\SI` command to get a correct  spacing between number and unit (`\,`). B.t.w., your comment in the preamble: `% Agrupamento de colunas em tabelas` seems to mean loading `multicol` is to merge columns in tables (I don't speak portuguese, but it's a Latin language…). If my interpretation is correct, it's wrong: multicol is to type part of a document in two (or  more) columns.

Comment: Bernard, thank you for all the corrections. is it possible put the words '' Drucker-Prager'' in the first column? like the image :